# Sonata Admin Bundle: DatePicker range

Tags: datepicker, symfony-2.1, jquery-ui-datepicker, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

How would I create a `doctrine_orm_datetime_range` filter in the Sonata Admin Bundle which uses the jQuery UI datepicker?

I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper
        ->add('datumUitgevoerd', 'doctrine_orm_datetime', array('widget' => 'single_text'), null, array('required' => false,  'attr' => array('class' => 'datepicker')))
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Using custom date picker is not needed anymore. Sonata contains native datetime picker, that works well with Twitter Boostrap.

To activate the datetime picker form fields, you have to enable loading the twig template that contains the related code.

### CONFIGURATION

For **Symfony 4**:

```
# config/packages/twig.yaml
twig:
    # ...
    form_themes:
        - '@SonataCore/Form/datepicker.html.twig'
```

For **Symfony 3**:

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    # ...
    form_themes:
        - 'SonataCoreBundle:Form:datepicker.html.twig'
```

For **Symfony 2**:

```
# app/config.yml:
twig:
    # ...
    form:
        resources:
            - 'SonataCoreBundle:Form:datepicker.html.twig'
```

### USAGE

You can use the picker in form definition:

```php
    use Sonata\CoreBundle\Form\Type\DatePickerType;

    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('createdAt', DatePickerType::class);
    }
```

in the datetime filter:

```php
    use Sonata\CoreBundle\Form\Type\DatePickerType;

    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        $datagridMapper
                ->add('createdAt', 'doctrine_orm_datetime', ['field_type'=> DatePickerType::class]);
    }
```

or as datetime range filter:

```php
    use Sonata\CoreBundle\Form\Type\DateTimeRangePickerType;

    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        $datagridMapper
                ->add('createdAt', 'doctrine_orm_datetime_range', ['field_type'=> DateTimeRangePickerType::class]);
    }
```

## OLD ANSWER

To use datePicker in `doctrine_orm_datetime` use this code:

```php
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper->add('datumUitgevoerd', 'doctrine_orm_datetime', array(), null, array('widget' => 'single_text', 'required' => false,  'attr' => array('class' => 'datepicker')));
}
```

Or to use datePicker in `doctrine_orm_datetime_range` the code should look like:

```php
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper->add('datumUitgevoerd', 'doctrine_orm_datetime_range', array(), null, array('widget' => 'single_text', 'required' => false,  'attr' => array('class' => 'datepicker')));
}
```

And you should overload main template to add your custom javascript file to initialize DatePicker.

```yml
#File app/config.yml
sonata_admin:
    title:      Admin
    title_logo: /logo_admin.png
    templates:
        layout: AcmeDemoBundle::standard_layout.html.twig  
 #...another Sonata and Symfony settings...
```

```twig
{# File src/Acme/Bundle/DemoBundle/Resources/views/standard_layout.html.twig #}
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/acmedemo/js/jquery_admin.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
 {% endblock %}
```

```js
 //File web\bundles\acmedemo\js\jquery_admin.js
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery.datepicker.setDefaults( jQuery.datepicker.regional[ "" ] );
      jQuery(".datepicker").datepicker( jQuery.datepicker.regional[ "en" ]);
 });
```

Comment: I followed your instructions, and it all works as expected until I hit the "Filter" button. I get a validation error for the date fields "This value is not valid." the one thing I'm currently doing different is I'm using the `'input_type' => 'timestamp'`, other than that is the same. The default date_range widget works just fine for me. Any ideas why?

Comment: The key to my problem was to set the correct format: `'format' => 'M/d/y'`

Comment: It seems that this solution does not work any more with Symfony 2.6 ... But  : `$datagridMapper->add('expirationDate','doctrine_orm_date_range',['field_type' => 'sonata_type_date_range' , 'field_options'=> array('widget' => 'single_text', 'required' => false, 'attr' => array('class' => 'datepicker'))]);`

Did the trick for me !

Answer (score 13):

I know that it's old topic, but it helps me a bit anyway, so maybe it will help somebody in the future.

I've find a way to set up a date format for datepicker:

```
$datagridMapper->add('createdAt', 'doctrine_orm_date_range', [
    'field_type'=>'sonata_type_date_range_picker',
    'field_options' => [
        'field_options' => [
            'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd'
        ]
    ]
]);
```

On default that format parametr is set up in Sonata\CoreBundle\Form\Type\DatePickerType.

Comment: Just what I was looking for, you only need to add template for date picker to config file also.

Comment: For those willing to use `doctrine_orm_datetime_range`, the format will be `'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'`.

Answer (score 5):

If you need a datetime range filter in Symfony 4

[image]

you can use:

```
# config/packages/twig.yml
twig:
    form_themes:
        - '@SonataCore/Form/datepicker.html.twig'
```

**Attention**: for **Sonata 3** you must use:

```
# config/packages/twig.yml
twig:
    form_themes:
        - '@SonataForm/Form/datepicker.html.twig'
```

admin class:

```
use Sonata\CoreBundle\Form\Type\DateTimeRangePickerType;

protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper): void
{
    $datagridMapper->add(
        'createdAt', 
        'doctrine_orm_datetime_range', [
        'field_type'=> DateTimeRangePickerType::class,
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

for **Sonata 3** you must use @SonataForm instead of @SonataCore:

```
# config/packages/twig.yml
twig:
    form_themes:
        - '@SonataForm/Form/datepicker.html.twig'
```

Answer (score 3):

In Symfony 4 I had to do the following for datetime filter:

```
# config/packages/twig.yml
twig:
    form_themes:
        - '@SonataCore/Form/datepicker.html.twig'
```

And in my admin class I had to configure the filter like this:

```
use Sonata\CoreBundle\Form\Type\DateTimePickerType;

...

protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper): void
{
    $datagridMapper->add('createdAt', 'doctrine_orm_datetime', [
        'field_type'=> DateTimePickerType::class,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: this is not working fine when we filter some data by any date, the filter got removed.