# SonataAdminBundle datepicker

Tags: datepicker, symfony, sonata-admin

I want to include a datepicker in my form. I find this :

```
twig:
debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
form_themes: 
    resources :
       - 'SonataCoreBundle::Form:datepicker.html.twig'
```

but when I clear the cache i have this message :

> [Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidTypeException]
>     Invalid type for path "twig.form_themes.resources". Expected scalar, but got array

I dont understand.
Can you explain me please.
Thank you

Comment: Try with this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14443558/sonata-admin-bundle-datepicker-range?answertab=votes#tab-top Remove "resources" path.

Answer (score 1):

Just delete `resources :` in your twig configuration.

Look this

```
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    form_themes:                 
        - 'SonataCoreBundle::Form:datepicker.html.twig'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example configuration for form type.

```
$formMapper->add(
        'createdAt',
        DateTimePickerType::class,
        [
            'label'             => 'Data utworzenia',
            'attr'              => ['style' => 'width:300px;'],
            'dp_side_by_side'   => true,
            'dp_use_current'    => false,
            'dp_use_seconds'    => false,
            'dp_collapse'       => true,
            'dp_calendar_weeks' => false,
            'dp_view_mode'      => 'days',
            'dp_min_view_mode'  => 'days',
            'format'            => 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm',
        ]
    );
```

This is working example, for SF 4.x